# Synchrotron Emission: Physical Intuition for the Broad Spectrum

Tags: astronomy, fourier-transform, pulsars, synchrotron-radiation

I understand what is happening to the electron to have it emit synchrotron light. However, I am not physically understanding the reason that a pulse of light that an observer sees will be made up of multiple frequencies or why there is a peak in the spectrum.

[image: Synchrotron Spectrum]

Many textbooks and videos just say that the Fourier transform of a pulse of light gives multiple frequencies; and I understand the math... but it doesn't make sense physically since I think the electron should be emitting the same wavelength of light. Is it because as the electron moves along the helical path, it slows down in a short amount of time (changing $\gamma$), emitting light of different wavelengths? Also, why is the arrival time of photons ($(1 - \beta)\Delta t_{emit}$) different than the emission time ($\frac{1}{\omega_{rot} \gamma}$)?

Comment: have you read this ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchrotron_radiation

Comment: And this? - [The Basics of Synchrotron Emission](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FnYNjKabmxU)

Comment: Yes, I have read/watched both of those. They only state that the Fourier transform of the light pulses (which I understand) result in a broad spectrum in frequencies. I get the math, but where are the frequencies coming from? Is something physically happening to the electron to make it emit different frequencies? Is it the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle? I know the math, but need a more physical connection.